# uninitialized constant Spree::User::DestroyWithOrdersError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I am a new to working with Spree and basically did the following:

git cloned the git hub repo and created a new project. I then looked in the core folder and took all the files I needed. The reason why I did this is purely because I wish to customise Spree and make some changes. I did a bundle install and tried doing a bundle exec rake db:reset and ran into an error that I have been trying to solve. I have looked in the following file

--> /`home/dj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/spree_auth 1.1.0/app/controllers/spree/admin/admin_users_controller_decorator.rb` which looks like the following: [Pastie](http://pastie.org/3910163). I also found the following github issue [github issue](https://github.com/spree/spree/issues/1155) that Ryan Biggs commented on. I tried this but had no luck.

What is it that I have done wrong here.

> uninitialized constant Spree::User::DestroyWithOrdersError
>   /home/dj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/spree_auth-1.1.0/app/controllers/spree/admin/admin_users_controller_decorator.rb:3:in
>
> `block in <top (required)>'
>   /home/dj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/spree_auth-1.1.0/app/controllers/spree/admin/admin_users_controller_decorator.rb:2:in`
>   class_eval'
>   /home/dj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/spree_auth-1.1.0/app/controllers/spree/admin/admin_users_controller_decorator.rb:2:in
>   `<top (required)>'
>   /home/dj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/spree_auth-1.1.0/lib/spree/auth/engine.rb:13:in`
>   block in activate'
>   /home/dj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/spree_auth-1.1.0/lib/spree/auth/engine.rb:12:in
>   `glob'
>   /home/dj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/spree_auth-1.1.0/lib/spree/auth/engine.rb:12:in`
>   activate'
>   /home/dj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:451:in
>   `_run__1016855746__prepare__693579178__callbacks'
>   /home/dj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in`
>   __run_callback'
>   /home/dj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in
>   `_run_prepare_callbacks'
>   /home/dj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in`
>   run_callbacks'
>   /home/dj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:74:in
>   `prepare!'
>   /home/dj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:48:in`
>   prepare!'
>   /home/dj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:47:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
>   /home/dj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in`
>   instance_exec'
>   /home/dj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in
>   `run'
>   /home/dj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in`
>   block in run_initializers'
>   /home/dj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in
>   `each'
>   /home/dj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in`
>   run_initializers'
>   /home/dj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in
>   `initialize!'
>   /home/dj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in`method_missing' /home/dj/Desktop/my_store/config/environment.rb:5:in
>   `<top (required)>'
>   /home/dj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in`
>   require_environment!'
>   /home/dj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:292:in
>   `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
>   /home/dj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in`
>   call'
>   /home/dj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in
>   `block in execute'
>   /home/dj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in`
>   each'
>   /home/dj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in
>   `execute'
>   /home/dj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in`
>   block in invoke_with_call_chain'
>   /home/dj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in
>   `mon_synchronize'
>   /home/dj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in`
>   invoke_with_call_chain'
>   /home/dj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in
>   `block in invoke_prerequisites'
>   /home/dj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in`
>   each'
>   /home/dj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in
>   `invoke_prerequisites'
>   /home/dj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in`
>   block in invoke_with_call_chain'
>   /home/dj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in
>   `mon_synchronize'
>   /home/dj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in`
>   invoke_with_call_chain'
>   /home/dj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in
>   `invoke'
>   /home/dj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in`
>   invoke_task'
>   /home/dj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in
>   `block (2 levels) in top_level'
>   /home/dj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in`
>   each'
>   /home/dj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in
>   `block in top_level'
>   /home/dj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in`
>   standard_exception_handling'
>   /home/dj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in
>   `top_level'
>   /home/dj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in`
>   block in run'
>   /home/dj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in
>   `standard_exception_handling'
>   /home/dj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in`
>   run'
>   /home/dj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in
>   `<top (required)>' /home/dj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake:19:in`
>   load' /home/dj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake:19:in `'
>   Tasks: TOP => db:reset => environment

Answer (score 2):

Djj,

The recommended method for installing Spree is:

```
$ gem install rails -v 3.2.3
$ gem install spree
$ rails new my_store
$ spree install my_store
```

You don't want to copy files directly into your app. http://guides.spreecommerce.com/customization.html has some good resources on customizing your site.

http://speakerdeck.com/u/jsqu99/p/spreeconf-2012-introducing-spree-10 has a good explanation of how a Spree app should be structured.